# Cross domain iframe in a safe way

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, postmessage, nuxt3

I want to see how secure it would be to use an iframe on a third party domain which would have access to our domain. We want to avoid authentication but it still needs to be secure. I am using nuxt3 for testing, as our domain runs this.

I believe that using `window.postMessage()` between the front-end domains along with `"frame-ancestors": "domain-to-whitelist"` in our backend is an OK way to bypass the same-origin policy.

```
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        'frame-ancestors': ['https://localhost:3008']
      },
    },
  })
);
```

My browser still complains when I try the `postMessage()`call to the domain which the iframe should display.

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:3008') 
does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

I cannot get a POC working and I am wondering whether this is a wild goose chase as bypassing the same-origin policy is inheritaley bad idea

Domain A - Parent to iframe

```
app.vue

   <iframe id="my-frame" sandbox="allow-scripts" height="200px" width="2000px"> 
    </iframe>
  
    onMounted(() => {
        document.getElementById('my-frame').contentWindow.postMessage({
        data: 'data',
     }, "http://parent-domain")
   })
```

Domain B ( content iframe should display eventually )

```
nuxt.script.js

  const domainRequest = (e) => {
      console.log('parent event', e);
    };
  
    window.addEventListener('message', domainRequest, false);
```

Comment: You don't have a `src` attribute on the iframe, so where & when are you actually loading content into it? Right now, the error message is complaining that its origin is _null_ - which would make sense, if you have not loaded any content from an actual HTTP(S) origin into it at that point.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, I am not referencing the child origin anywhere. thanks